# How to produce same width pages in wkhtmltopdf in different computers

Tags: html, css, asp.net, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2 is used to create pdf files in Windows 7 x64 and Windows 10 x64 from same html with options:

```
C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe --lowquality -L 0mm -R 0mm -T 0mm -B 0mm --dpi 96 --zoom 1.6 - -
```

exe file is invoked from from ASP.NET MVC 4 controller.

In Windows 10 developement computer running from Visual Studio/IIS Express text zoom is less and there is appox 2 cm right margin (empty space)

In Windows 7 production computer runnning from IIS pdf zoom is bigger and text ends in right edge of page.

How to fix this so that same width page is created always ?

html code used to generate pdf and wkhtml version are same in both Windows computers.

However result pdf sizes are dirrerent: 36663 and 30814 bytes.
How to compare pdf and find reason why pdfs differs ?

posted also in

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3165